# Having trouble defining a function with head Superscript

Tags: functions, function-construction, built-in-symbols

I wish to define a function in the following form,

```
Superscript[Subscript[Γ, i_, j_], k_][g_, var_List] := 
  Block[{ginv = Inverse[g], n = Length[var]}, 
    Sum[
      ginv[[k, l]] (D[g[[j, l]], var[[i]]] + D[g[[i, l]], var[[j]]] - D[g[[i, j]], 
      var[[l]]]), {l, 1, n}]];
```

However, whenever I input something of the form

```
Power[Subscript[Γ, 1, 1], 1][g, var]
```

`Power` simplifies and the expression doesn't evaluate. Is there any way to redefine the meaning of a `Superscript` in this context? I've tried unprotecting both `Superscript` and `Power`, but neither of those options worked.

Comment: Might you provide the motivation for this wish?  There may well be a better approach.  (E.g., is your core concern the display of the expression in a notebook?)

Comment: In Riemannian geometry, we denote this term by $\Gamma_{ij}^k$, and that is the form that I'm used to seeing. More or less, I'm trying to keep my notation as close to standard mathematical notation as possible.

Comment: My question is whether you care about how you type it, or how it displays.  E.g., suppose your define `Format[G][i_, j_, k_]] := 
 DisplayForm@
  RowBox[{SubsuperscriptBox[G, RowBox@{i, ",", j}, k]}]` (but replace G with a capital gamma).  Then you would type `G[i,j,k]` but it would display as you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of directly using `Superscript` and `Subscript` in the function definition, you could create an `InputAlias` that is entered by typing <kbd>esc</kbd>`gam`<kbd>esc</kbd> to create a template of the desired form. With that template, you can define an `InterpretationFunction` that tells *Mathematica* what to do with the input once the template has been filled in.

For your function, I would recommend restricting it to act only on numeric values of the arguments `i`, `j`, `k`, because they appear as array indices in the evaluation. Your definition is contained in a differently named function `myGamma` to separate it from the formatting-related definitions. This is implemented below:

```
ClearAll[myGamma]

GammaAppearance[i_, j_, k_] := 
 TemplateBox[{i, j, k}, "myGamma", 
  DisplayFunction :> (SubsuperscriptBox["Γ", 
      RowBox[{#1, ",", #2}], #3] &), 
  InterpretationFunction :> (RowBox[{"myGamma", "[", 
       RowBox[{#1, ",", #2, ",", #3}], "]"}] &)]

myGamma[i_?NumericQ, j_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := 
 Function[{g, var}, 
  Module[{ginv = Inverse[g], n = Length[var]}, 
   Sum[ginv[[k, l]] (D[g[[j, l]], var[[i]]] + D[g[[i, l]], var[[j]]] -
        D[g[[i, j]], var[[l]]]), {l, 1, n}]]]

myGamma /: MakeBoxes[myGamma[i_, j_, k_], StandardForm] := 
 GammaAppearance[ToBoxes[i], ToBoxes[j], ToBoxes[k]]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Join[{"gam" -> 
      GammaAppearance["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]", 
       "\[Placeholder]"]}, 
    InputAliases /. 
      Quiet[Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]] /. 
     InputAliases -> {}]]
```

The `SetOptions` adds the input alias to the list of abbreviations known to the notebook in which you're currently evaluating commands. It's written with a `Quiet` wrapper to suppress warnings when there aren't any existing aliases yet.

If you now press <kbd>esc</kbd>`gam`<kbd>esc</kbd> and enter $\Gamma_{i,j}^{k}$ with symbolic indices, the template remains unevaluated and displays just as you want. But if the indices have numerical values, the function definition is invoked:

```
gTest = DiagonalMatrix[{x y, y z, z x}];
varTest = {x, y, z};
```

[image]